# Create a matrix using elements of other matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, conditional-statements

I have two matrices `a` and `b` (with equal number of columns). I want to create a third matrix `c` using a condition:

For example, I have:

```
a = [1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4; 
     1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3]

b = [5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16;    
     17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28;    
     29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40]
```

The condition is: `a(2, :) == 2`, so the resulting matrix should be:

```
c = [1 2 3 4;
     2 2 2 2;
     9 10 11 12;
     21 22 23 24;
     33 34 35 36]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
%With your a and b

cols = a(2,:) == 2;
c = [a(:,cols) ; b(:,cols)];

c =

 1     2     3     4
 2     2     2     2
 9    10    11    12
21    22    23    24
33    34    35    36
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should work.  By all means probably not the best and most efficient way to do it.

```
a=[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4;  
   1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3];

b=[5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16;     
  17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28;     
  29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40];

truthtable = a(2,:)==2;
c = []
for idx = 1:length(truthtable)
    if truthtable(idx) == 1
       c(:,end+1) = [a(:,idx);b(:,idx)];
    end
end
```

Comment: @EitanT I would love to have input on what would make it better practice then.  I also believe that I mentioned that it wasn't likely to be the best or most efficient way to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: @BenA. Well, for starters, suggesting `for` loops when you obviously can use simple logical indexing is anything but good.